# getting a classCastExcption while making a navigation drawer

Tags: android

getting a classCastException:

android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: post relevant code snippet

Comment: Please provide code. It says you should use layout params of drawer layout...saying only exception is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the sample code, you might want to have a look at the Google code. Good sample code.
NavigationDrawer:https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html